# Unexpected identifier while doing Mongoimport of json file

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName < /Users/pratikjoshi/Desktop/FileName.json --jsonArray
```

I run this command in shell scripts!

Here is my json file content

```
[  
   {  
      "trackingRecordId":5742294,
      "longitude":77.126205,
      "latitude":28.54711,
      "batteryPerc":100,
      "speed":0.13,
      "createdOnDt":"2016-01-14 00:00:01"
   },
   {  
      "trackingRecordId":5742293,
      "longitude":72.86727,
      "latitude":19.112692,
      "batteryPerc":51.82,
      "speed":10,
      "createdOnDt":"2016-01-13 23:59:59"
   }
]
```

Comment: can u show me your json file, pastebin or anywhere.

Comment: [{
  "trackingRecordId" : 5742294,
  "longitude" : 77.126205,
  "latitude" : 28.54711,
  "batteryPerc" : 100,
  "speed" : 0.13,
  "createdOnDt" : "2016-01-14 00:00:01"
 },
 {
  "trackingRecordId" : 5742293,
  "longitude" : 72.86727,
  "latitude" : 19.112692,
  "batteryPerc" : 51.82,
  "speed" : 10,
  "createdOnDt" : "2016-01-13 23:59:59"
 }]

Comment: this is absolutely valid json, i don't know what was the problem

Comment: Is there any mistake in command???

Comment: your command is just fine, see my answer, there was some issue with your json file i guess. which is Okay now.

Answer (score 0):

Well it clearly shows that your JSON is corrupted,
just goto [JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), validate your JSON file and try again.

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

Well your json is completely valid and your command for export is also valid and working pretty much OK with me.

[image]

Comment: I run command on Robomongo's Shell window. Is it ok? or any other way to run command. I am using mac.  Can we run this command from terminal? If so, then what's way?

Comment: you need to create a ~/.bash_profile and assign /usr/local/mongodb/bin to the $PATH environment variable and after that you can run it like mongoimport

Comment: I have set $PATH variable and then check by this command "echo $PATH" It gives me output: "/usr/local/mongodb/bin" Then I execute my command for mongoimport .  But, it not work it's output is "-bash: mongoimport: command not found"

Comment: see if it is working like this /usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongo, if it is means this was the correct directory

Comment: Yes, It's working in my system. Thank you so much for your guidance.